# Vimのキーバインドで<C-Up><C-Down>を使いたい

Tags: vim

.vimrcに以下の様に書いても機能しません。

```
nnoremap <C-DOWN> 5j
```

CTRLキーと矢印（上下）キーを同時に押したときに、行スキップを行いたいのですが、上記の方法ではできませんでしょうか。どのようにしたら実現できるか、ご教示ください。OSX ターミナル使用、Vimのバージョンは以下の通りです。

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jan 31 2019 16:45:22)
macOS 版
適用済パッチ: 1-850
Compiled by Homebrew
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOSの標準のターミナルではうまくいきませんでしたが、iTermならうまく動きました。
　その際、「システム環境設定」ー「キーボード」ー「Mission Control」で「^↓」のチェックを外す必要がありました。
　標準のターミナルでなければならないのでなければ、iTermを検討してみてください。

Comment: itermを使うことで実現できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 5):

これはvimではなく端末に関する問題です。グラフィカル版のvimのほうが一般的に `<C-Down>` その他のような特殊なキーの組み合わせを理解するのに適しているので、こちらを使うほうがよいでしょう。私はOSX上ではあまりvimを使ったことがないので、デフォルトでグラフィカル版のvimが付いているかどうか覚えていません。しかし、"MacVim"は非常に人気のあるバージョンで、おそらくあなたにとってはうまくいくはずです。

MacVimを入手したら、マッピングはあなたが書いた方法でうまく動作するはずです。私が "Gvim"（Windows上）で試したとき、それは完璧に動作します。

---

文法や単語の選択がおかしいと思われる場合は申し訳ありませんが、Google Translateを使用しました。 :)

Comment: Your second sentence ("グラフィカル版のvimを使いたいのですが、...") is a bit hard to follow. Could you share your original sentence so that I can update your answer in Japanese?

Comment: @yosh Sure, thank you! "You should use the graphical version of vim, since it's generally better at understanding strange combinations of keys, like `<C-down>` and others."